# Which layer is the intermediate between Linux and Sound Card?

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, audio

I want to create a virtual sound card, where I can process the input and send a prepared output to other different and real(/virtual) sound cards and its channels.

I have an algorithm to create 8 channel from 2 input channel and I want to create a software for Linux (for now) that is able to utilize all the current sound cards and its channels to create a 7.1-like audio system with any stereo played in the system sound.

I developed the SDL2.0 player, and it is working. Now  I want to try to be in the middle of the way between the OS playing sounds and the speakers in a programmatic layer to do there the job.

If for example we have the following scenario, the programming will be in the layer "intermediate":

SDL2.0 -> intermediate -> kernel -> sound card

I know that probably there are more layers inside the intermediate layer. But I hadn't study the scenario enough. What layers are there, and how can I insert my algorithm in these layers?

Comment: Virtual hardware devices require drivers, which are OS-specific. Driver development for any of those is not nearly as easy as writing simple programs. And you seem to be struggling with the latter still. Someone with enough experience would have set easier intermediate goals, e.g. playing a single WAV file with 7.1 channels using just your own application.

Comment: Okay, then I am going to think about researching of an SDL2.0 application that plays the most channel available I have over the available physical/hardware interfaces. Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable way to get the math ironed out.

Comment: Okay, then I am going to think about researching of an SDL2.0 application that plays the most channel available I have over the available physical/hardware interfaces. And later to return back to the main project and feed it back, to see how it helped to develop the main goal. Ironed out would be possible if they didn't close my question, but it's okay. They do for themselves. Good luck and thank you.

Comment: The banner above the question says that the question can be reopened if it's fixed. But in this case that would need a rather big rewrite. I.e. you would have to start coding your SDL application, and then come up with one specific coding question. At the moment, the only question mark is in the title, and that question is indeed far too broad.

Comment: I understand, understood... it is for security reasons. Nice then. Actually I am reading about how to do it with SDL2.0 but... in any case, that question is well done because the main goal is to evolve the actual situation about music, tech, software/hardware and sound/audio and I choose this platform because is the only I knew, know that it is good enough to solve big questions even sometimes questions are more specific I saw after post, (before I hadn't be aware of), the good of this website and platform, etc to improve this topic. Sincerely I don't know how to make it specific but I try to.

Comment: Can you please re-open the question?

Comment: I've removed some of the old stuff, but kept the new stuff. It's now in the review queue.